# Why can't I display more data from firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know I am making a mistake somewhere. I am trying to display all food items from my firebase database onto my restaurant website. So far, I can only display "all_Day_Special" and not anything else.

```
import './Home.css';

import React from "react";
//import Categories from "./Categories";
//import items from "./data";
import { all_Day_Special, menu_Add_Ins, menu_Appetizers, menu_Beef, menu_Chicken, menu_Chow_Mein,
  menu_Combinations, menu_Deep_Fried_Goodiness, menu_Dessert, menu_Flavor, menu_Fried_Rice, menu_Hot,
  menu_Pork, menu_Seafood_Platter, menu_Sides, menu_Vegetable, menu_Whats_Cooking, menu_Wing } from './firebase/firebaseConfig';
import { useState, useEffect, ReactDOM} from 'react';
import {collection, doc, setDoc, addDoc, getDocs} from 'firebase/firestore';

function Menu() {

  const [food, setFood] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getFood = async () => {
        const data = await getDocs(all_Day_Special, menu_Add_Ins, menu_Appetizers, menu_Beef, menu_Chicken, menu_Chow_Mein,
          menu_Combinations, menu_Deep_Fried_Goodiness, menu_Dessert, menu_Flavor, menu_Fried_Rice, menu_Hot,
          menu_Pork, menu_Seafood_Platter, menu_Sides, menu_Vegetable, menu_Whats_Cooking, menu_Wing);
        setFood(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id})));


        

    };
    getFood();
  }, []);

return(
      <div className='menu'>
        <div className="top-section"></div>
          {food.map((item) => {
            return (
              <article key={item.id} className="menu-items">
              <img src={item.ImageURL} alt={item.Name} className="photo" />
              <div className="item-info">
                <header>
                  <h4>{item.Name}</h4>
                  <h4 className="price">${item.Price}</h4>
                </header>
                <p className="item-text">{item.Description}</p>
              </div>
            </article>
          );
        })}
        </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default Menu;
```

I'm thinking I would need to make more constants? It does seem repetitive and I'm sure it can be done in a more efficient way.

[image: getDocs() from FireMenu.js file]

Comment: Can you share what are all those parameters being passed in `getDocs()` ?

Comment: Hey @Dharmaraj I uploaded photos of my "FireMenu.js" file with the getDocs().

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the **getDocs()** function's first param is a `collection` or a `query`, so if you want to get docs from multiple collections like what you're doing, you need to repeatedly call `getDocs()` on individual collections.

What you're doing will likely result in Firestore only returning the docs from `all_Day_Special`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not fetch multiple collections like that, but mainly you must have setup your firebase too complex... here is how I could do it

**Firebase**
Here is how my firebase would be structured:
I could first have a `collection` called `"menu"` then let firebase generate `doc.id` for me and in my `document` will have the following object structure...

```
name: "shrimp",
price: 10,
category: "sea",
special: true //all_day_special as a boolean,
spicy: boolean //you can add whatever categories
```

This way you will be able to call one function and get everything you need easily, then your firebase would look something like this:

```
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

//use query to get specific items
useEffect(()=>{
const q = query(collection(db, "menu"), where("special", "==", true));
const getFood = async () => {
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => setFood({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id}))
}
getFood()
},[])

//to get all items in the menu collection use the below::

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "menu"));
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => setFood({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id}));
```